# Extract BLOB File as multiple files in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, blob

I want to extract original files stored as `BLOB` in `DB2` database. 
I used this `DB2` command:

```
EXPORT TO MyFile.DEL OF DEL LOBS TO . LOBFILE lob SELECT BLOB_COL 
FROM MY_TABLE where REPORT_ID in
(select report_id from My_TABLE2 where CONDITION)
```

I get a `.blob` file that contains the content of all the files. 
Now I am wondering if there is a way to export each file in a single file instead of having them gathered in the same file.

Is this possible in DB2 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible in recent versions of DB2 for LUW (beginning at least with v9.5) by specifying the `lobsinsepfiles` modifier:

```
EXPORT TO MyFile.DEL OF DEL LOBS TO . LOBFILE lob 
MODIFIED BY lobsinsepfiles
SELECT ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can store the LOBs in different files by adding the keyword `lobsinsepfiles` to your `EXPORT` statement. [See here for details](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dm.doc/doc/c0004562.html?lang=en). There are also options to specify how the individual file names should be constructed which I would recommend to use.

Your statement would look like:

```
 EXPORT TO MyFile.DEL OF DEL LOBS TO . LOBFILE lob
 MODIFIED BY lobsinsepfile
 SELECT BLOB_COL FROM MY_TABLE where REPORT_ID in
 (select report_id from My_TABLE2 where CONDITION)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your favourite DB tool: [SQL Workbench/J](https://www.sql-workbench.eu/), [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/), [SQuirreL SQL Client](http://www.squirrelsql.org/), [DbVisualizer](https://www.dbvis.com/), [QMF for Workstation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/qmf/13.1.1?topic=qmf-workstation-qmf-websphere) and others. They all have ability to download the LOB files form a database column. Refer to the help for finding the correct settings to enable LOB files extract. Then run a query that extracts the column with the LOB files, export as CSV and set the folder where your exported files will be saved. Rename them after exporting.

The below is a guide on how to export BLOBs on the server side, compress, download, clean up the server storage, extract the downloaded files, rename them.

1. Find out who is the team that manages the server where your DB2
   resides,
2. get secure shell (ssh) access to the server,
3. have your tools ready: I use Fedora Linux, but you can do with Windows and Mac, just search or talk to the server managers (this is why first step was to find out who they are),
4. ask the server managers to give you the procedure for connecting to the DB2 using the server OS with ssh. Below is the way they told me to do it:

```
ssh server.com
<login>
. /home/dbadminuser/sqllib/db2profile
db2  connect to DATABASE
cd /db/dbadminuser/db2backup/export
```

Export all attachments on batches of 1 year

```
db2 "export to ATTACHMENTS2023.del of del lobs to . modified by lobsinfile lobsinsepfiles select RECNO, SEQNO, FILENAME, ATTACHMENT from PCT.ATTACHMENT where ROW_UPDATE_DT BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2024-01-01'"
```

compress

```
tar cf - *2023* | gzip -9 > lob2023.tar.gz
```

clean up

```
rm ATT*
```

download the file using secure copy (scp)

```
scp server.com:/db/dbadminuser/db2backup/export/*2023* ~/Downloads/db_backup/
```

cleaned up the rest on the server machine after all downloads completed:

```
rm *.tar.gz
```

Extract the archives. Here how it can be done in Linux.

```
tar xzf lob2023.tar.gz
```

Take care to rename the "del" file

```
mv ATTACHMENTS2023.del ATTACHMENT2023.csv
```

Add the column names in its top row.

There is much more efficient ways to do this, I am just using "vi" text editor.

```
vi ATTACHMENT2023.csv

i for insert
new first line:
"RECNO","SEQNO","FILENAME","ATTACHMENT"
Esc for quit the insert mode
:wq for write and quit vi
```

Here I should have checked the encoding of the files names in ATTACHMENT.csv for any wrong displays of "£", "€", "μ", "û", "ó", and other special characters. I fixed those much later.

When the downloads are complete, you will have a folder with 1 csv file and many lob1.001 to lobn.nnn where "n" is a digit, which you would like to rename. In this table, we have the file names in a column Filename.

For my particular needs, wanted to have a folder structure of each record in separate folder with all its files, named with record number_sequence number_filename (because 2 files can have the same name, but different sequence):
RECNO/RECNO_SEQNO_FILENAME

I used PowerShell (latest version) to do this automatically (yes, yes, there are other better programming languages, and I had time to learn this one for this task):

1. it reads the CSV file, understanding that the first line holds the column names,
2. then uses the column names as variables holding each row's values,
3. using those variables, it creates folder for each
   record
4. and "moves" the file to its new name.

There may be a more optimal way to do this, I just used this one.

```
PS > Import-Csv .\ATTACHMENT2023.csv -Delimiter "," | ForEach-Object -Process {New-Item -Path "." -Name ($_.RECNO) -ItemType "directory"; Move-Item ($_.ATTACHMENT) -Destination (".\" + $_.RECNO + "\" + $_.RECNO + "_" + $_.SEQNO + "_" + $_.FILENAME)}
```